# In SQL Server: Create Pivot Table with each Date as a own column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have a table containing 4 different identifiers, a date and a numeric column like:

```
ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | my_date | in_stock
A | A | A | C | 06.06.2020 | 2880
A | A | A | C | 05.06.2020 | 2880
A | A | A | D | 06.06.2020 | 5000
A | A | A | D | 05.06.2020 | 6000
```

from which I want to create a kind of pivot table like the following:

```
ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | 05.06.2020| 06.06.2020
A | A | A | C | 2880 | 2880
A | A | A | D | 6000 | 5000
```

This should be created for past 10 days or so, so it CRUCIAL I don't have to set the dates manually. I tried something with PIVOT but that didn't work out so I switched to do the job with `CASE WHEN` like the following:

```
SELECT ID, ID2, ID3, ID4, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN my_date = DATEADD(DAY, -0, (SELECT MAX(my_date) FROM my_table)) then in_stock END) DATEADD(DAY, 0, (SELECT MAX(my_date) FROM my_table)),
    SUM(CASE WHEN my_date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, (SELECT MAX(my_date) FROM my_table)) then in_stock END) DATEADD(DAY, -1, (SELECT MAX(my_date) FROM my_table))
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, ID2, my_date, ID3, in_stock, ID4
    FROM RIAMDB.dbo.my_table my_table
    WHERE (my_date>DATEADD(DAY, -2, (SELECT MAX(my_date) FROM my_table)))
) src
GROUP BY ID, ID2, ID3, ID4
```

but that still doesn't work out as I get

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'DAY'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near 'src'.
```

How would you guys approach this issue is CASE the right way to do it or rather use PIVOT somehow? Or is there any s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for a **Dynamic Pivot**

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 Into  ANewTable
 From  (
         Select ID1
               ,ID2
               ,ID3
               ,ID4
               ,My_Date
               ,In_Stock
          From  YourTable
          Where my_date>= dateadd(DAY,-10,convert(date,getdate()))
        ) src
 Pivot (sum(In_stock) For [my_date] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct concat(',[',my_date,']') 
                                                    From  YourTable 
                                                    Where my_date>= dateadd(DAY,-10,convert(date,getdate()))
                                                    Order By 1 
                                                    For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p
'
--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL);

Select * from ANewTable
```

**Returns**

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 ID4 2020-06-05  2020-06-06
A   A   A   C   2880        2880
A   A   A   D   6000        5000
```

EDIT - Last Update - Next time ask a new question

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 Into  ANewTable
 From  (
         Select ID1
               ,ID2
               ,ID3
               ,ID4
               ,Col = concat(''t-'',datediff(day,my_date,getdate()))
               ,In_Stock
          From  YourTable
          Where my_date>= dateadd(DAY,-10,convert(date,getdate()))
        ) src
 Pivot (sum(In_stock) For [col] in (' + Stuff((Select concat(',[',col,']') 
                                                    From  ( Select top 10 
                                                                   my_date
                                                                  ,col=concat('t-',datediff(day,my_date,getdate()))
                                                             From  YourTable
                                                             Where my_date>= dateadd(DAY,-10,convert(date,getdate()))
                                                             Group By my_date 
                                                             Order By my_date desc
                                                          ) A
                                                     For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p
'
--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL);

Select * from ANewTable
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input, that's a new but promising option. I can't really say i totally understand the code, but where do I close the last parenthesis, isn't there one missing? somehow I get the following error: Msg 102, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near 'p'.
Msg 137, Line 7
Must declare the scalar variable "@SQL". Do you know what's wrong here?

Comment: @Quastiat Sorry, bad copy/paste   I was missing the final closing single quote

Comment: my bad that was kind of a obvious one. However I still have some questions: 1) how do I restrict the number of columns (lets say I on top of ID1-4 i have some columns col1-10 that are in this list but I don't need?) I added a group by clause for ID1-4, but I want to exclude any other column 2) how do i restrict the output to contain only the last 10 dates in this manner? Thank you very much already!

Comment: @Quastiat See my updated answer.  Rather than From YourTable, we simply added a subquery detailing the desired columns and included a WHERE my_date ...

Comment: @Quastiat Just rember, you need to "Feed" PIVOTS with the desired columns.

Comment: Wow thats amazing thank you works exactly as I expected it to! I will need some time tomorrow to really understand what's actually happening here but that is exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: @Quastiat Always happy to help.  Uncomment the Print SQL.  This way you can see the SQL which is executed.

Comment: thanks for the hint. One final question is there actually a way to change the order of the date columns so it starts with the latest date in descending order? Or is there a easy way to change th column names in t, t-1, t-2 etc?

Comment: @Quastiat  change Order By 1   to   Order By 1 Desc

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, is it possible to store this query into a view or table? Is OPENROWSET a way to achieve this or is there a easier way?

Comment: @Quastiat Sure, I updated the answer where the results are stored INTO ANEWTABLE    Then you Select * from ANewTable  .  A word of caution, you may have to DROP the table if it already exists.

Comment: Is there a way to change the column names from dates to t-1, t-2, ... ,t-10? or maybe automatically change them after the table is created?

Comment: @Quastiat See EDIT

Comment: @Quastiat Just an afterthought, in the two places you see datediff(day,my_date,getdate())   depending on the desired order you may want to flip the parameters  of my_date and getdate() or even change  Order By my_date desc to Order By my_date asc

Comment: thank you, you're an lifesaver! I really need to work more with SQL directly instead of adjusting the tables later on, a lot of stuff can be done there directly I see

Comment: @Quastiat As long as you keep asking "Is there a better way?", you'll be fine.   If you find yourself doing things manually ... stop ... and look for a data driven solution.  Keep watching SO, I learn something every day.  That's the fun part.  :)